# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I'm switching my log4j config from PatternLayout to JasonLayout. After the change, I started having the following error:

```
ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout for element JsonLayout: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/FilterProvider
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.<init>(JsonLayout.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout.<init>(JsonLayout.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout$Builder.build(JsonLayout.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.JsonLayout$Builder.build(JsonLayout.java:79)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1138)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1063)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:1055)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:664)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:621)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:694)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
    at de.ic_consult.planetarium.listener.ListenerEmbedded.<clinit>(ListenerEmbedded.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 21 more
```

This class comes from jackson-databind, which in my case, is version 2.13.1, that comes as dependency from [log4j 2.17.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.17.2).
I'm using gradle to manage the dependencies, and the log4j dependency comes from an internal framework, in which I saw that log4j is loaded as:

```
  implementation('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api')
  runtimeOnly('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core')
  runtimeOnly('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl')
```

Could it be that the fact that I'm loading log4j-core and logj4-jcl as runtimeOnly is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jackson-databind` is an **optional** dependency of `log4j-core`. Basically it means that if you want to include it, you'll have to declare it explicitly as dependency on your project (cf. [Maven optional dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.